# ruby 1.9.1 in netbeans?

Tags: ruby, netbeans

i have installed ruby 1.9.1 and when i in the command prompt type:

ruby -v

i see the latest version.

however, in netbeans when i create a new project i can only select 1.8.7 version.

how do i tell netbeans to use the latest ruby version that i have installed?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add your own Ruby platform. [See this tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/61/ruby/setting-up.html#native).